# How do I make a TLS connection using the rustls library?

Tags: ssl, rust

The [documentation](https://docs.rs/rustls/0.10.0/rustls/) provides an example — unfortunately it does not compile; a lot of stuff got renamed and the interface of the `ClientSession` constructor changed. I managed to fix the errors to a point where it compiles, but not to a point where it works.

Here is my best attempt at getting the minimum example to work:

```
extern crate rustls;

use io::Read;
use io::Write;
use rustls::Session;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut socket = std::net::TcpStream::connect("www.google.com:443").unwrap();
    let mut config = rustls::ClientConfig::new();
    config
        .root_store
        .add_server_trust_anchors(&webpki_roots::TLS_SERVER_ROOTS);
    let arc = std::sync::Arc::new(config);
    let dns_name = webpki::DNSNameRef::try_from_ascii_str("www.google.com").unwrap();
    let mut client = rustls::ClientSession::new(&arc, dns_name);
    client.write(b"GET https://www.google.com\r\n\r\n").unwrap();
    loop {
        if client.wants_read() {
            client.read_tls(&mut socket).unwrap();
            client.process_new_packets().unwrap();
            let mut plaintext = Vec::new();
            client.read_to_end(&mut plaintext).unwrap();
            io::stdout().write(&plaintext).unwrap();
        }
        if client.wants_write() {
            client.write_tls(&mut socket).unwrap();
        }
        // For testing purposes only
        std::thread::sleep_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

What happens is that the program starts to run and aborts after 10 seconds with the error "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine."

I would have expected it to print some data to stdout, which it does not.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a struct called `rustls::Stream` to use the session as a normal stream. It's documented on [docs.rs](https://docs.rs/rustls/0.17.0/rustls/struct.Stream.html). You can also find an example [on their GitHub repository](https://github.com/ctz/rustls/blob/master/rustls-mio/examples/simpleclient.rs).

You can convert your code to use `rustls::Stream` like this:

```
extern crate rustls; // 0.17.0

use io::Read;
use io::Write;
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut socket = std::net::TcpStream::connect("www.google.com:443").unwrap();
    let mut config = rustls::ClientConfig::new();
    config
        .root_store
        .add_server_trust_anchors(&webpki_roots::TLS_SERVER_ROOTS);
    let arc = std::sync::Arc::new(config);
    let dns_name = webpki::DNSNameRef::try_from_ascii_str("www.google.com").unwrap();
    let mut client = rustls::ClientSession::new(&arc, dns_name);
    let mut stream = rustls::Stream::new(&mut client, &mut socket); // Create stream
                                                                    // Instead of writing to the client, you write to the stream
    stream
        .write(b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n")
        .unwrap();
    let mut plaintext = Vec::new();
    stream.read_to_end(&mut plaintext).unwrap();
    io::stdout().write_all(&plaintext).unwrap();
}
```